# Deselect text in a textbox

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a windows form that sets the text property in a textbox to that of a string variable.  When the form is ran, it has all of the text in the textbox selected.  I need to try and figure out how to keep that from happening.  I tried the

```
DeslectAll()
```

method on the textbox but that doesn't seem to work.  I also tried

```
txtBox.SelectNextControl(txtCostSummary, true, false, true, true);
```

but I kind of was guessing on what the paramters needed to be set to, tweaking them doesn't seem to make a difference.  To really understand what I'm doing I'll make it a little more clear on how this all is happening.

```
public Form1()
{
    Apple a = new Apple();
    a.IwantThisText = "Item 1: " + 50.00 + "\r\n";
    txtBox.Text = a.IwantThisText;
}

Class Apple
{
    private string iWantThisText;
    public string IwantThisText
    {
    get { return iWantThisText; }
    set { iWantThisText += value; } // Appends what was there before
    }
}
```

Everything works fine except the part where it has printed the information in the textbox but all the text in the textbox is selected, which isn't what I thought would happen, nor is it what I want to happen.

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Try this:

```
txtBox.Select(0, 0);
```

Comment: Sorry, been a while since I've been on here heh.  Sorry for the super late answer.

Comment: It should be txtBox.Select(txtBox.SelectionStart, 0) as it won't move the caret to 0.

Answer (score 19):

I know it's an old question, but I found that this works too:

```
txtBox.SelectionLength = 0;
```

This might be preferable to @SteveCav's `Select(0,0)` as it doesn't move the selection start point.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
//remove focus from control.
Apple a = new Apple();    
a.IwantThisText = "Item 1: " + 50.00 + "\r\n";    
txtBox.Text = a.IwantThisText;

// Add this
txtBox.TabStop = false;
```

Comment: +1 because I didn't know the TabStop property would solve this.

Comment: Setting the .TabStop property false on my RO textbox was all I needed. Very nice -- thank you.